# Need for m.initial_state.eval() in TensorFlow PTB tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the PTB language model tutorial at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py.
I don't understand the need for line 248 (and the passing of state into session.run on line 254)

`state = m.initial_state.eval()`

Isn't the tensor of the initial state:

`self._initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)`

evaluated when the graph is loaded into the session?

For example, this code prints 11 as one would expect,

```
x = constant(6)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
z = x + y
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(z,{y:5})
```

without the need to replace the last line with 
`print sess.run(z,{y:5,x:x.eval()})`

So is that eval needed? And if so, why?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out. The RNN is called multiple times, and each time it is called you want it to start with a clean initial state. If you were to just call it once, you wouldn't need to pass in a clean initial state to `sess.run()`.